# Add tag to RichEditBox Selection

Tags: c#, tags, uwp, selection, richeditbox

Is there any way to add a tag to a `RichEditBox.Document.Selection`?

I though about using a dictionary with start and end position, but if we add text before selection, it is not possible...

I want to let user add files/folder in it, and eventually resize images, so i need to know wich image was clicked/selected

Comment: Though problem! - If you can control/track the edits you might be able to update the Dictionary.. You could tag/mark a space character by setting its forgroundcolor but when the user deletes it it is gone..

Comment: yea i know, but if it was a more simple way would be cool too :/